# Superblock set in the future, hwclock attempting to debug it

Tags: ssd, filesystems, troubleshooting, clock

I keep getting errors messages about my Superblock mount time being in the future, and  insisting on doing fsck on every other boot, Im worried it will mess up my SSD.

Where is the last time coming from? Its off 7 hours, could that be the cause?

```
hwclock from util-linux 2.20.1
Using /dev interface to clock.
Last drift adjustment done at 0 seconds after 1969
Last calibration done at 0 seconds after 1969
Hardware clock is on unknown time
Assuming hardware clock is kept in UTC time.
Waiting for clock tick...
...got clock tick
Time read from Hardware Clock: 2013/09/18 21:28:18
Hw clock time : 2013/09/18 21:28:18 = 1379539698 seconds since 1969
Wed Sep 18 14:28:18 2013  -0.411186 seconds
```

Comment: Are you dual-booting Windows? Linux usually assumes the hardware clock is set to UTC, whereas Windows generally wants it to be local time - maybe one or the other is changing it unexpectedly.

Comment: Yes, I am running windows although I have not booted into it for a while and not at all since I installed linux.

Comment: Where is the second time "Wed Sep 18 14:28:18 2013  -0.411186 seconds
" coming from? The time on my panel matches my Hw Time.

Comment: You don't happen to live in UTC-7, do you?

Comment: Actually yes I do, and my hardware clock is exactly -7 hours off of that second line. The Hw clock time is correct, the last line is not. I have UTC=no

Comment: Well, that's definitely the problem - for some reason the system is confused as to which time setting is correct. Where is that setting? For example, in Debian using `/etc/default/rcS` is deprecated, and you should set LOCAL in `/etc/adjtime` instead.

Comment: Ohhh:D that would help to know about it, and not surprisingly its set to '0.000000 1379573459 0.000000
1379573459
UTC'

Comment: What distro are you using? The best thing to do is to set the hwclock to UTC in the BIOS - this should fix any issues, otherwise you will have to find workarounds. Check [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Time) for more information.

Comment: Im using Mint 13, setting UTC to LOCAL made no difference, the two times now match. Still getting superblock set in the future.

Comment: It's probably because the clock gets set multiple times during boot, introducing a bit of error in the wrong direction. Setting your RTC (the BIOS clock) to universal time should fix it.

Comment: Issue is UTC doesn't work with dual boot, and I would like to pinpoint where this is happening. Its pretty much a clean install.

Comment: It should work with the registry change specified in the article I linked above. I'm not aware of any other way to fix this. If you still insist on having the BIOS clock in local time, you might want to ask a different question..

Answer (score 0):

With the help of user55325 and some work on the terminal myself I think I have got this fixed:

First I did what user55325 recommended:

1. set /etc/default/rcS utc=yes and adjtime last line back to UTC
2. Set bios time to utc time.
3. hwclock -s -u
4. boot into recovery mode and selected clean
5. reboot back into Mint
6. date, verifying everything was ok
7. Boot into Windows synced time with ntp server
8. Checked bios time, it was now set to localtime
9. booted into Mint again
10. hwclock -s -u set /etc/default/rcS utc=n0  and adjtime last line back to LOCAL
11. from recovery mode ran clean and fsck

Result: After many reboots and general use, Now both Mint and Windows 8 are showing localtime and boot without errors.